# how to use div scroll instead of the body scroll

Tags: css

i have this simple `div` that has some text in it , and this css

```
#mydiv{
    width:100px ; 
    height :300px;
    border : 1px solid black ; 
    overflow : auto
}
```

so far the `div` has no scroll , when i minimize the window's height the body scroll appers
so you can see the content of that `div`

**See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/29JRB/)**

**QUESTION**
How can i disable the body scroll and use the div scroll instead , make the div always visible 
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure there is enough content to make the div scroll....in your example, it fits nicely.
Here is the adjustment:

```
#mydiv{
 width:300px ; 
 height :100px;
 border : 1px solid black ; 
 overflow : scroll;    
}
```

Comment: what i am trying to do is i want the div to be visible with out scroll when the height is 300px and then when you min. the window height the div scroll should appears

Comment: In that case I think you should get some scriping involved. Bind on the window resize event and if the height gets below 300, set the css height property of the div to 100%. That should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
body,html{
    overflow:none;
}
```

Should suffice

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:hidden to the body and enough content to fill the div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/29JRB/23/)**

```
#mydiv{
    width:100px ; 
    height :300px;
    border : 1px solid black ; 
    overflow : auto

}

body {
    overflow:hidden;
}​
```

Comment: no if you set the height to 300 and then min. the window you will get the body,html scroll not the window scroll